# Where to elastic server logs in localhost?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

My elastic search server is hosted in port 9200.
My application server makes request to the ES server.
I would like to see the request params and the request URL that hits the elastic search server.
Where can I see these?

OS: macOS Mojave

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Unix based OS, you should be able to find the Elasticsearch logs in:

`/var/log/elasticsearch`

I'd also check the messages in `/var/log/messages`, to tail & filter for Elasticsearch:

`tail -f /var/log/messages | grep elasticsearch`

Comment: I am using mac OS and in var/log folder there is no file or folder with name elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows system, then open `elasticsearch.yml` file under *`config`* folder and uncomment below line and provide your local path

```
  path.logs: <local_path>
```

Save the `elasticsearch.yml` file and start the server.

Now you can see all the logs under your local path.

Comment: No am I using macOS

Comment: Even macOS also it’s same...Open elasticsearch.yml file and check logs path or you can change it if required.

Comment: Where should I find elasticsearch.yml? Will it be part of my application?

Comment: It will be as part of elasticsearch setup. Go to path the path where you installed elasticsearch in your Mac machine.